# Bring launched processes to foreground in OSX?

Tags: macos, iterm2, window-focus, macos-mojave

I recently installed the suite of qemu utilities (using `brew` if that matters) on OSX Mojave. QEMU is working as expected, though it does not have focus when launched from the terminal (iTerm, specifically). The QEMU instance will always be draw behind the currently active terminal window. If the terminal window itself is expanded to take the entire screen, then the launched QEMU instance is entirely covered.

Is there a way to set this ordering? Given how rendering works in OSX, is iTerm responsible for this or is QEMU forcing itself into the background? Alternatively, is there a way to set the focus to a particular pid/process after it has launched?

---

I am working on a project that requires me to launch QEMU about as often as one might `make` then test any other code, so having to find QEMU is pretty annoying.

Comment: Does QEMU look like any ordinary app in the dock? [It's not a process I'm familiar with]. If it does, you can lock the two to different spaces & just flip between them at will.

Comment: @Tetsujin, How might one do that? But no, QEMU is not an Application. It's a standalone binary, like many other utilities launched from a terminal. It's one binary located in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: You'd have to check this against the behaviour for 'regular' apps, as I can't test it here. Right click it in the Dock > Options > Assign to... pick a Desktop. Repeat for iTerm. Set each to a different Desktop/Space. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for a fuller explanation.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I tried assigning QEMU to a desktop but it didn't appear to affect which it was launched into; it would always just launch into whichever the terminal was in. I also noticed that QEMU _would_ launch into another Desktop _only if_ I had the terminal in fullscreen mode (i.e. consuming the navigation bar). Still not quite what I wanted. If you desire to test, you can just `brew instal qemu` if you already have `brew`. The binary I've been using it called `qemu-system-x86_64`. Launching it with no arguments will still show the behavior I'm describing.

Comment: I don't use homebrew at all, so it's not something i can easily test, sorry.